# CSRFGuard : required token is missing from the request

Tags: security, csrf

I have set up a simple project, based on struts. Trying to implement CSRFGuard into it.

Here is the csrfguard.properties files:

```
org.owasp.csrfguard.Logger=org.owasp.csrfguard.log.JavaLogger
org.owasp.csrfguard.configuration.provider.factory = org.owasp.csrfguard.config.overlay.ConfigurationAutodetectProviderFactory
org.owasp.csrfguard.Enabled = true
org.owasp.csrfguard.ValidateWhenNoSessionExists = false
org.owasp.csrfguard.NewTokenLandingPage=%servletContext%/Login.do
org.owasp.csrfguard.TokenPerPage=true
org.owasp.csrfguard.TokenPerPagePrecreate=false
org.owasp.csrfguard.Rotate=true
org.owasp.csrfguard.Ajax=true
org.owasp.csrfguard.unprotected.Default=%servletContext%/
org.owasp.csrfguard.unprotected.JavaScriptServlet=%servletContext%/JavaScriptServlet
org.owasp.csrfguard.unprotected.Error=%servletContext%/error_page.jsp
org.owasp.csrfguard.unprotected.Index=%servletContext%/index.jsp
org.owasp.csrfguard.unprotected.Scripts=%servletContext%/scripts/*
org.owasp.csrfguard.unprotected.Styles=%servletContext%/styles/*
org.owasp.csrfguard.unprotected.Images=%servletContext%/images/*
org.owasp.csrfguard.action.Log=org.owasp.csrfguard.action.Log
org.owasp.csrfguard.action.Log.Message=potential cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attack thwarted (user:%user%, ip:%remote_ip%, method:%request_method%, uri:%request_uri%, error:%exception_message%)
org.owasp.csrfguard.action.Redirect=org.owasp.csrfguard.action.Redirect
org.owasp.csrfguard.action.Redirect.Page=%servletContext%/error_page.jsp
org.owasp.csrfguard.action.Rotate=org.owasp.csrfguard.action.Rotate
org.owasp.csrfguard.TokenName=csrfToken
org.owasp.csrfguard.SessionKey=csrfToken
org.owasp.csrfguard.TokenLength=32
org.owasp.csrfguard.PRNG=SHA1PRNG
org.owasp.csrfguard.PRNG.Provider=SUN
org.owasp.csrfguard.Config.Print = true
org.owasp.csrfguard.JavascriptServlet.sourceFile =  WEB-INF/conf/csrfguard.js
org.owasp.csrfguard.JavascriptServlet.domainStrict = true
org.owasp.csrfguard.JavascriptServlet.cacheControl = private, maxage=28800
org.owasp.csrfguard.JavascriptServlet.refererPattern = .*
org.owasp.csrfguard.JavascriptServlet.refererMatchDomain = true
org.owasp.csrfguard.JavascriptServlet.injectIntoForms = true
org.owasp.csrfguard.JavascriptServlet.injectGetForms = true
org.owasp.csrfguard.JavascriptServlet.injectFormAttributes = true
org.owasp.csrfguard.JavascriptServlet.injectIntoAttributes = true 
org.owasp.csrfguard.JavascriptServlet.xRequestedWith = OWASP CSRFGuard Project
org.owasp.csrfguard.configOverlay.hierarchy = classpath:Owasp.CsrfGuard.properties, classpath:Owasp.CsrfGuard.overlay.properties
org.owasp.csrfguard.configOverlay.secondsBetweenUpdateChecks = 60
```

Here is the snippet from my web.xml

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>Owasp.CsrfGuard.Config</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/conf/csrfguard.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>Owasp.CsrfGuard.Config.Print</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardHttpSessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CSRFGuard</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CSRFGuard</filter-name> 
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

When I start the application, and give its url, it loads the login page properly. And this is an unprotected page.
Next when I hit login, it goes in to process the request. When I debug code, I can see tokenFromPages and tokenFromSession having values. But the variable tokenFromRequest is coming in as null. And since this is coming as null, it is throwing the "required token is missing from the request" exception.
File: CsrfGuard.java
Method: verifyPageToken
Condition where the exception is being thrown:

```
if (tokenFromRequest == null) {
    /** FAIL: token is missing from the request **/
    throw new CsrfGuardException("required token is missing from the request");
}
```

Could anyone help me please. Please let me know if you need any more information too.

Adding logs to show issue:

```
URL: http://localhost:8080/App1/Login.do?csrfToken=GQQD-MEJT
```

I clicked login on page, and below are the logs generated. I have no clue why it shows null for tokenFromRequest.

```
Aug 29, 2014 8:33:03 PM org.owasp.csrfguard.log.JavaLogger log
INFO: CsrfGuard analyzing request /App1/Login.do
tokenFromPages --> N92E-COOR
tokenFromSession --> KLGU-DDRZ
tokenFromRequest --> null
Aug 29, 2014 8:33:03 PM org.owasp.csrfguard.log.JavaLogger log
WARNING: potential cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attack thwarted (user:<anonymous>, ip:127.0.0.1, method:POST, uri:/App1/Login.do, error:required token is missing from the request)
Aug 29, 2014 8:33:03 PM org.owasp.csrfguard.log.JavaLogger log
INFO: CsrfGuard analyzing request /App1/error_page.jsp
Aug 29, 2014 8:33:03 PM org.owasp.csrfguard.log.JavaLogger log
INFO: CsrfGuard analyzing request /App1/Login.do
tokenFromPages --> GQQD-MEJT
tokenFromSession --> CD7O-C556
tokenFromRequest --> GQQD-MEJT
```

Comment: http://localhost:8080/App1/Login.do is the default url. When I click login, it shows up http://localhost:8080/App1/Login.do?csrfToken=GQQD-MEJT

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: No Neeraj. Would need to try the below solution.

Answer (score 1):

Please try leaving the NewTokenLandingPage property empty.

Modify/Comment
org.owasp.csrfguard.NewTokenLandingPage=%servletContext%/Login.do

to

org.owasp.csrfguard.NewTokenLandingPage=

I would also suggest to take it step by step.
Do not enable page tokens and token rotations in the first go. Rotations and page tokens can introduce many issues. First get it to work with a session token and then progressively enable features.

Comment: I shall try this out and let you know. Thank you Santon.

Comment: @Sri did you find a solution to this? I'm also receiving the 'required token is missing from the request' message.